# Render a 404 page on its own without any other components with React Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working with `reacter-router-dom@6.4.2` and I have the following code:

**index.tsx**

```
const container = document.getElementById("app")!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And in my **App.tsx** I have:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="patients/:patient" element={<Patient />}>
          <Route path="overview" element={<Overview />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In the Chrome console, I get the following warning:

```
utils.ts:767 You rendered descendant <Routes> (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/" (under <Route path="/">) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.

Please change the parent <Route path="/"> to <Route path="*">.
```

Why am I getting this warning and what can I do to fix it?

I still get the warning even if I remove `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />` from my `App.tsx`

Right now, only the `/` routes works. It renders the `<Sidebar />` and the `<Home />` components. But if I go to `http://localhost:3000/patients/blah/overview` I get the `<NotFound />` component when I should be getting the `<Overview />` component (at least that's what I want to be getting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App` component is rendering descendent routes, so the parent route should append a trailing `"*"` wildcard matcher to its route.

Example:

```
const container = document.getElementById("app")!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

To handle "unknown" routes the descendent `Routes` component necessarily needs to render another `NotFound` route.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="patients/:patient" element={<Patient />}>
          <Route path="overview" element={<Overview />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

If the `App` component is really only serving as a "layout route" to render the `Sidebar` component with specific routes then I suggest converting it to an actual layout route.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
const container = document.getElementById("app")!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="patients/:patient" element={<Patient />}>
              <Route path="overview" element={<Overview />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese, if I do that and navigate to `/calendar` I get the `<Sidebar />` rendered when I expect `<NotFound />`

Comment: @J86 With descendent routes each descendent `Routes` component needs to render its own "unknown" route. If you convert to using a layout route and nested routes then the single `Routes` component handles all the route path matching.

Comment: Thank you, the trick was in creating a layout route. Much appreciated Drew <3